# Create a mongodb text index with no default language

Tags: mongodb, text, indexing

I'M trying to create a text index without a default language. The official docs specify `If you specify a language value of "none", then the text search uses simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming.` Hence I tried:

```
createIndex({aliases : "text"}, {name : "aliases_txt"}, {default_language: "none"})
```

However the created index ignores my option and has "english" as default language:

```
{
"v": 1,
"key": {
  "_fts": "text",
  "_ftsx": 1
},
"name": "aliases_txt",
"ns": "ner-dict.ents",
"weights": {
  "aliases": 1
},
"default_language": "english",
"language_override": "language",
"textIndexVersion": 2
}
```

version: `mongod-3.0.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, in your solution, the `name` value is ignored. If you want to specify both index name and default_language, you need to use:

```
db.textTest.createIndex({aliases : "text"}, {name : "aliases_txt", default_language: "none"});
```

with both `name` and `default_language` in the same 'options' document parameter.

Comment: Oh right, `createIndex` expects 2 arguments exactly, nice catch. I wish js would throw an error on extra args.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to change the order:
`db.ents.createIndex({aliases : "text"}, {default_language: "none"},  { name: "aliases_txt"})`

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, then. Be aware though, that without a language, no stemming and no stop words are provided.