# Mongoose, cannot create text index with default_language: 'none'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to create search feature using `$text` and `$search` in mongoose but it stuck when the query meet mongodb english `stop words`. I try to change my default_language to none to ignore the `stop words` list but then I realized that I cannot change the default_language.

I was wondering the way my mongoose always create index with default_language: english, even I directly use `default_language: 'none'`.

Here is my code:

```
kataSchema.index({ kata: "text" }, { default_language: 'none' });
```

and then when I open mongo shell and type db.katas.getIndexes(), it's always showing me this:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "kata_text",
        "background" : true,
        "weights" : {
            "kata" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

I also try to delete the index in mongo shell and run my code again but it still use english as its default_language.

Do I miss at something or else? I was already searching for it everywhere but still cannot find the issue. Thanks for advice.

mongoose version: "^5.10.0"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879398/create-a-mongodb-text-index-with-no-default-language

Comment: @Muslim thank you, I have tried that but mongoose still generate default_language to english. I wonder how people done this issue in mongoose instead of in mongodb native driver solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem comes from the **.index** itself .. Use **[createIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)** instead.

In your model's schema, try this:

```
.
.
.
const Kata = mongoose.model('Kata', kataSchema);
Kata.createIndexes({ kata: "text" }, { default_language: 'none' });
```

Comment: Thank you I use your advice, the native driver syntax createIndex, but it still generates english as its default_language

Comment: the code: `Kata.collection.createIndex({kata: "text"},{ default_language: "none" });`

Comment: createIndexes and not createIndex ... there are difference between them

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Anyway it still generate english as its `default_language`. Then I use `ensureIndex` and its working fine but now I got deprecated message since it's already deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Had quite the same issue with Mongoose **5.10.0** and MongoDB **4.4.0**:

```
contentSchema.index(
{
    title: "text",
    shortDescription: "text",
    description: "text",
},
{
    weights: {
        title: 10,
        shortDescription: 5,
        description: 1
    },
    default_language: "german",
    name: "SearchIndex"
});
```

**weights** and **default_language** were just ignored. Updating Mongoose:

```
npm update mongoose
```

Mongoose is now version **5.10.16** and **default_language** as well as **weights** are working correctly without any code modifications.

**You will have to drop the wrongly created index first before the new one is applied.**